# Using apply on large ffdfs

Tags: r, bigdata, apply, ff

The basic idea is this: I have a large `ffdf` (about 5.5 million x 136 fields). I know for a fact that some of these columns in this data frame have columns which are all `NA`. How do I find out which ones and remove them appropriately?

My instinct is to do something like (assuming `df` is the `ffdf`):

`apply(X=is.na(df[,1:136]), MARGIN = 2, FUN = sum)`

which should give me a vector of the `NA` counts for each column, and then I could find which ones have ~5.5 million `NA` values, remove them using `df <- df[,-c(vector of columns)]`, etc. Pretty straightforward.

However, `apply` gives me an error.

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 21.6 Mb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In `[.ff`(p, i2) :
  Reached total allocation of 3889Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In `[.ff`(p, i2) :
  Reached total allocation of 3889Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In `[.ff`(p, i2) :
  Reached total allocation of 3889Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In `[.ff`(p, i2) :
  Reached total allocation of 3889Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

This tells me that `apply` can't handle a data frame of this size. Are there any alternatives I can use?

Comment: How about just `df[, !colSums(is.na(df[,1:136]))==nrow(df)]` ?

Comment: @zx8754 Do you mean `colSums` instead (see my previous edit)? Either way, I still get the same error.

Comment: @zx8754 Just saw your edit, will try that

Comment: @zx8754 However, I would be interested in getting the list of columns that are removed as well, but I suppose that wouldn't be too difficult.. just compare the `names`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to use `all(is.na(column))`. `sapply`/`lapply` donot work because and `ffdf` object is not a list.

You use `df[, 1:136]` in your code. This will cause `ff` to try to load all 136 columns into memory. This is what causes the memory issues. This does not happen when you do `df[1:136]`. The same happens when indexing for the final result: `df <- df[,-c(vector of columns)]` reads all selected columns into memory.

```
na_cols <- logical(136)
for (i in seq_len(136)) {
  na_cols[i] <- all(is.na(df[[i]]))
}

res <- df[!na_cols]
```

Comment: Similar error when declaring `cols`: `Warning messages:
1: In ff::`[.ff`(x = x, i = i, pack = pack) :
  Reached total allocation of 3889Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In ff::`[.ff`(x = x, i = i, pack = pack) :
  Reached total allocation of 3889Mb: see help(memory.size)`

Comment: @Clarinetist I saw the discussion in the comments under your question and modified my answer. Your error is caused because your code reads the complete data set into memory.

Comment: `cols` worked, `df[, !cols]` gave me a similar error.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was the intent, but `cols` only has two values: under `virtual`: `FALSE`, and under `physical`: `FALSE`.

Comment: @Clarinetist You are right. `sapply` doesn't work. The toy example I used to test the code worked because I accidentally happened to have the same number of columns as returned by `sapply`. My new code should work not.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
#dummy data
df <- sample(1000000*5)
df <- data.frame( matrix(df,nrow = 1000000))
df$X3 <- NA
df$X6 <- NA

#list of col to remove or keep
colToRemove <- colnames(df)[ colSums(is.na(df[ ,1:6])) == nrow(df) ]
colToKeep <- setdiff(colnames(df), colToRemove)

#subset
res <- df[, colToKeep]

colnames(df)
#[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5" "X6"
colnames(res)
#[1] "X1" "X2" "X4" "X5"
```

Comment: Works fine on my end.